# CakePHP Complicated authentication (specific user roles to specific controllers/areas)

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to build a small web app that will have several areas:

1. Users area
2. Admins area

I'm using the Auth component and checking after login the `Auth->user('role')` but this won't prevent a "normal user" typing the admin path in the URL and accessing it (he's logged in). Naturally the admins should be able to access any area but that's not my current problem :)

What is the best way of managing and more importantly implementing these kind of permissions/authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Auth::sessionKey](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$sessionKey). That is the way I manage it, using diferent keys for diferent roles ("Admin" and "User").

Answer (score 1):

There is ACL. However, I would discourage anyone from using ACL if they can stay away from it. Role Base Authentication is certainly good and easy to implement. They way you are starting out is correct, however, you need to enable `admin routing` in the `core.php` file.

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

Once that is done, the coding is setup accurately and authentication is inplace, only users with the role of `admin` will be able to access any admin section, such as `http://www.yoursite.com/admin/users`

Most magic for the Role Base Authentication to be successfull is done in the `AppController` class.

Just to give you an example, I would setup the `AppController.php` file this way:

```
public $components = array(
    'Cookie',
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                )
            )
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);


public function isAuthorized($user){        
    if(isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to have an `admin` layout and a `members` general layout, you can do so in either the `beforeFilter()` or `beforeRender()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `isAuthorized` function in your controller

Sample like this:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public function isAuthorized() {
        if($this->Auth->user('role_id' != '1')) return false;
    }
}
```

and in your `AppController beforeFilter()` add

```
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';
```